# Ubuntu 22.04 on ThinkPad E14 G3 not connecting to visible wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless, thinkpad

On my Lenovo ThinkPad E14 G3, with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installed, I continue to have trouble with the wifi connections.

The problem is basically that known networks, with password and everything already saved, show up in the list of available networks, but the connection attempts always fail. If I go really close to the router, it usually works and then also it keeps the connection even if I move further away. Then also the download speed and everything is fine.

The things that are really hard to understand for me are that I already searched online for solutions and nobody is complaining about hardware-related weak connections for the E14, and if you have to go to a distance of 2 meters to the router to connect I would assume a lot of other people would have complained. To make it even worse, if I go to the wifi settings, the signal strength is "good", but still no connection possible. Only if I go closer to the router.

I don't think the router is the problem because I tested it in at least 5 different locations with I think 3 different router manufacturers and it is the same everywhere.

Usually the online results for this problem are wifi not available, not connecting at all, too slow... so I did not found a solution yet. I checked somethings I found about energy-saver settings, but I think they all were as they should be.

Is there any other software option that can cause this issue? Or is there a hardware problem maybe? But then still I'm confused why the signal strength is supposedly good.

Comment: this sounds like your wifi is set to the wrong channel or too many wifi networks using the same channel.

Comment: With your laptop in its usual location, please run: `nmcli device wifi list` What is the SIGNAL of the router to which you are trying to connect? 95? 90? 85??

Comment: I just checked at home and both my routers are set to different channels as the surrounding routers, but both lead to the same problem

@chili555: the one I am trying to connect is actually really low, only 10 to 20. What is odd: the one I am connected to, which is only 1 meter away of the laptop, the signal varies between 30 and 80 but is on average only around 35-40. but the one I was trying to connect in the morning before writing the question was better than that, although I don't have the exact numbers

Comment: I wonder if *both* of the antenna wires are firmly snapped in place. https://content.spiceworksstatic.com/service.community/p/post_images/attached_image/d5142330-5419-490c-9fd1-5ca118b215d8-wlan1.jpg

Comment: I don't know if that messes with the warranty if I open it up? In principle I could also send it in for repair, as 11 month of warranty are left, but I wanted to exclude that it is software related, like drivers or so

Comment: I suggest that you ask the manufacturer about the warranty.

Comment: Update: I had a lot of discussion with lenovo. They were surprisingly stubborn and insisted that the problem is, that I have ubuntu installed although it is supposedly a "windows machine". Ultimately they told me to send it in for repair, but in this case clearing my data and installing another OS. I insisted on the antennas and finally I got the clearance for checking them without loosing warranty. It is as expected, one antenna was loose, so I reconnected it and everything is fine now. Thanks again @chili555 for leading me to the right path and saving me weeks of repair waiting.